# How to encrypt/decrypt larger file using RSA/AES

Tags: c++, openssl, aes, rsa

Okay so i'm looking for a way to encrypt/decrypt larger files using RSA and AES.
I don't quite understand what I need to do.

The scenario is that i've got larger files (anywhere from 200kb - 50mb). I want to be able to encrypt specific files leaving a key (private key) in the current directory as well as the encrypted file. The user can then save the key, take it with them and come back to decrypt the file at a later time.

I just don't quite understand how to use AES/RSA together to achieve this. I have some code to do simple RSA encryption/decryption and some working AES code. I got this code from other SO questions.

I'm using Openssl with C++.

Current AES program: (from online)

```
int main() {

int bytes_read, bytes_written;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

  /* ckey and ivec are the two 128-bits keys necesary to
  en- and recrypt your data.  Note that ckey can be
  192 or 256 bits as well */
  unsigned char ckey[] = "thiskeyisverybad";
  unsigned char ivec[] = "dontusethisinput";

  /* data structure that contains the key itself */
  AES_KEY key;

  /* set the encryption key */
  AES_set_encrypt_key(ckey, 128, &key);

  /* set where on the 128 bit encrypted block to begin encryption*/
  int num = 0;

  FILE *ifp = fopen("out.txt", "rb");
  FILE *ofp = fopen("outORIG.txt", "wb");

  while (true) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, ifp);

    AES_cfb128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, ivec, &num,
      AES_DECRYPT); //or AES_DECRYPT

    bytes_written = fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, ofp);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE)
      break;
  }
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This edit doesn't fix the issue. _" I have some code to do simple RSA encryption/decryption and some partially working AES code (encrypt works fine but cannot decrypt past certain file size)."_ Then show that code as a minimal sample and exactly explain what problems you have (compiler/runtime errors aso.).

Comment: The code doesn't add anything, i'm looking for others to suggest ways to implement this who may have done this in the past. But i'll add what I have in if it means that much to you.

Comment: Then your question is off-topic as mentioned in the first comment. Or even simply _too broad_ (which is another off-topic close reason).

Comment: No it really isn't. The only issue was me asking for resources which I have fixed.

Comment: Why do you wan to use RSA and AES?  Why not just use AES?

Comment: I read combining it would have the effect I desire.
Remember I want the user to be able to take the unlocking key away with them on a USB disk for example. Could I do this with just AES?

Comment: RSA is for secure communication between anonymous users, I don't think it applies here. You just need AES and a key, 128 bit or 256 bit (not simple text password). You drive the key from a password, you need a key derivation scheme. The password is required to be extra strong in this case because it's open to brute force attack, for example 15 characters long or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Okay so i'm looking for a way to encrypt/decrypt larger files using RSA and AES. I don't quite understand what I need to do...

All you need to do is:

- Generate random AES key
- Encrypt large file under AES key
- Encrypt AES key under RSA key

Also, encryption alone is usually not enough. That means your choice of AES/CFB could be improved. That's because CFB (and other modes like CBC) provide confidentiality only. You cannot detect accidental and malicious tampering.

To improve upon the mode, you should select a mode that provides confidentiality and authenticity. AES/GCM would be a good choice. There's an example of it on the OpenSSL wiki at [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption).

You can read more about Authenticated Encryption on the Crypto++ wiki at [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption). Its a different library and different wiki, but it provides the information on authenticated encryption.

In an ideal world, OpenSSL would provide an Integrated Encryption Scheme like Shoup's [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf) (ECIES) or Abdalla, Bellare and Rogaway's [Diffie-Hellman Authenticated Encryption Scheme](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/dhies.html) (DHAES). An integrated encryption schemes does it all for you.

By the way, [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com) is a C++ crypto library that provides both integrated encryption schemes. Maybe you should consider switching security libraries. Here's the documentation with sample code on [ECIES](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Ecies).

Comment: I don't understand the roles of RSA here. Here is one option: 1) Use PBKDF2 etc. to make AES key. 2) Pass the key through secure channel to the other user, it's done. The only problem is if secure communication is not available. That would be a job for RSA to make it available. Authentication of large files (up to 50 Mb) seems like overkill. I understand how it's possible to mess with small files in CTR/OFB mode, but any tempering with CFB/CBC will ruin the whole file. Maybe I need to start a new question about that.

Comment: @Barmak - *"I understand how it's possible to mess with small files in CTR/OFB mode, but any tempering with CFB/CBC will ruin the whole file. Maybe I need to start a new question about that."* - no need to start a new question. Read the article on Authenticated Encryption. It tells you everything you need to know. Or look at [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34380/Authenticated-Encryption) on Code Project. I was able to tamper with a sample license file and change `licenses=10` to `licenses=30`, `50` and `70` using CFB mode :) No decryption required.

Comment: @Barmak - *"... the only problem is if secure communication is not available..."* - OK, now that's a different requirement. Your original question lead me to believe it was local, long term storage. For secure communications, you need a Key Agreement algorithm like Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman (including EC variants), MQV, Fully-Hashed MQV, etc. You should probably move the discussion to the [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) so you can discuss the requirements and design of the security architecture.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused about what RSA is.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For this project I don't need to verify integrity so the Authenticated Encryption is not exactly what I am looking for (but was great to read about, thanks!). However, you have set me on the correct path, I will be encrypted using AES and then securely transferring the AES key using RSA keys.